# Vertical two head Slider iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, slider

I am trying to implement vertical two header slider with labels moving with head displaying min max values like in attachment. Can anyone help me out with libraries or anything

[image]

Comment: You can search CocoaControl for two header slider with labels moving with head. To make it vertical, just apply transform of 90 degree.

Comment: i have used most of CocoaControl, but after applying CGAffineTransformRotate it disturbs all other view and does not work

Comment: Applying CGAffineTransformRotate could disturb other views only if you add added other views constraint dependent on slider. So make sure you have not add any constraint dependent on slider for any other view.

Comment: yes Surjeet is right it'll work fine too (even better). You could disable auto-resize, or set a constraint for the slider you're rotating so the size doesn't change after rotation.

Comment: yes no constraints depends on slider view ,if i keep slider view initially horizontal and apply CGAffineTransformRotate than only view gets transform not the slider ,its like vice versa only one from slider view and slider gets vertical

Comment: done......!!!!!